# Keep element in the same position after resizing it using jQuery Isotope

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I'm planning to use the [jQuery Isotope plugin](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) similarly to the [official "Elements Complete" Isotope demo](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/elements-complete.html), in which clicking on any element makes it larger.

In the demo, when an element expands, it generally expands down and to the right (i.e. anchored by its top left corner). But click on any element in the two rightmost columns: it floats down and all the way to the left, since there isn't any room for it to expand rightward.

Ideally, for my application, an element on the right would expand to the left when clicked, thus staying in approximately the same position.

Basically, I'm looking for suggestions on how to optimize for maintaining element position after a `reLayout`. (Maintaining the order of elements isn't important for my application.)

Comment: i wounder if there  was no `diamond` against your name there would be comments like `better suited for programmers` or `what have you tried` `:p`

Comment: @3nigma how would a question like this ever belong on programmers.se?

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL isn't that the site for programming related discussion question like `looking for` etc or may be i wanted to mention `codereview` but there was no code involved ... any way it was supposed to be a `by the way comment ...`

Answer (score 1):

Give each element a number, and sort by number. If the page is 10 elements wide, 8 9 and 10 would wrap around. when one is clicked to resize, give it the number 7 and resort by number.

Let's say you took 10 and made it a 7, then sorted by number, now you'd have 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 7BIG 8 9 on a row

As far as I know, you can't cause jquery to resize to the left, rather than the right, unless you hack it with css padding or something like that..

Good luck